# I look for template engine with special concept

Tags: php, python, templates, node.js, frameworks

Please may you recommend me a HTML template engine (any of scripting languages) which realize special concept described below.

All markers are active. Data should be not prepared before calling template, but template itself got data from Model. For example

{CurrentUser.name}  will be replaced by name of current logged user, so I don't need to prepare data before calling template.

But also I can specify some "custom" data methods. For example if I have to make photogallery, and need only show a chunk of photos, I can use {PhotosListPart.thumb.url} and define special method for retrieving PhotosListPart, allowing to template automatically call it and get data asyncrounously.

Do you know any template engine / framework which supports this method of templating ?

Comment: This sounds like JSP custom tags or the original ASP, both old, but both can work that way. Now that I think of it I could use Jade this way if I pass in a context object. Whether data is prepared in advance or obtained when requested depends on the design of that object.

Comment: What template engine can't be used this way?

Comment: @joshp May be any engine, but not natively. For example, Smarty absolutely required to have prepared data passed to template engine. I want to have active templates which can address to almost any property of any system object.

Comment: @joshp Could you show an example of Jade used in this conception ?

Comment: Describe how you want to use it. I cant imagine how you want write web app without views.

Comment: @Denis MVC it just an concept, it not means that Views should be separate classes. I can be also active templates. In my imagine I think most of "modern" View code are actually prepares data to fill the template. I think it can be removed at all by using active templating which I've described in my topicstart message.

Comment: Yes I understand what MVC only design pattern, but I cant imagine how you want implement url routing and call templates from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull views are, views that *pull* data from the controller (which in turn calls the model to find the data).

If you strictly respect the MVC pattern[1], then you wouldn't be using any kind of *pull* views.

But AFAIK none[2] of the templating engines out there repspect MVC because they allow logic in the templates (if/foreach/function calls, etc.).

No templating engine will have pre-written code that assumes the presence of any data but almost all of them allow you to pass one single *huge* array of data filled with absolutely everything you need on a page.

If you need a *templating engine* that pre-populates data into variables, that's not a templating engine, that's a whole application, it contains logic which communicates with databases or models which takes it far away from the concept of templating engines.

[1] Respecting MVC when we talk about templating engines means using *if* only to check if a variable *is set*, for/foreach loops should not be present, ranging over a set/list of items is done by applying a template to the collection object, that and other concerns are illustrated here: http://bit.ly/Jc3f0Z

[2] Except: **StringTemplate** in Java, C# & Python; **Moustache** in a lot of languages including JS/Node.js/Java/PHP/Python/Ruby.

### Edit

Using View classes to prepare data, and template files to output them always seamed like a kludge to me because the names become confusing (Views are classes + templates, templates are files).

That's why I name my preprocessing classes "Renderers" and my template files "Templates" so Renderers+Templates =  Views. Which makes more sense to me as a name and as a philosophy.

I can use money_format/number_format/html_escape etc. within the renderers and then output already rendered data into the templates. Therefore I don't mix rendering/viewing actions with the controller. They all get done in the Renderer.

Comment: @Epsiloncool Out of curiosity... what did you choose to use in the end? Name your poison boy!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I understand what MVC only design pattern, but I cant imagine how you want implement url routing and call templates from it. For example you get request from user and you need show some data if you remove views all your business logic should be locate at models or at templates or elsewhere like helpers and so it turns out MVC but views to smeared on three places or more. But if you really want do this you can try to use Mako templates http://www.makotemplates.org/ with it you can write python code directly in templates as you want ))

Comment: Actually I can write PHP code in templates natively, but I don't want. I also don't say about we don't need views at all, I just meant it is possible to shrink views site dramatically by removing data preparing from it and using active templates, having direct access to models, instead.

Comment: With mako you can do this maybe with small hacks.